# Why it is "eine Scheibe Käse" but "ein Portion Salat"?

Tags: gender, article

It is *die Scheibe*, *der Käse*, *die Portion* and *der Salat*. Why do they have different indefinite articles?

Comment: They don't. The correct inflection is "eine Portion", no matter what food you use it with.

Comment: Hm, I'm wondering if we should close the question because it's based on a mistake, or if we should answer this question with "you've made a mistake".

Comment: At the moment, this is being closed as off-topic. Maybe if you can add your source it can be reopened/the closing prevented.

Answer (score 3):

<del>*Ein Portion Salat*</del> is simply incorrect; as you point out, *Portion* is feminine so the indefinite article must be *eine*.

The genus of the second noun — cheese and salad in your examples — is irrelevant, by the way. In this construction, the first noun carrying an article describes the quantity of the second noun; the latter never carries an article. Since the article belongs to the first noun, all three grammatical genders can follow without the article changing:

> Ich nehme eine Scheibe Brot (neuter), eine Scheibe Käse (masculine) und eine Scheibe Wurst (feminine).